# Adding github self-hosted runner gives /proc/self/exe running config.sh error

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to add a github self-hosted runner. When I get to the part where I am supposed to execute config.sh, I get the following message:

Failed to resolve full path of the current executable [/proc/self/exe]. Any pointers on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the full log, if possible. Also, the error in the title is different from the description?

Comment: Sorry..just edited the title. It originally gave me a must not run with sudo error but I resolved that one and then this new error popped up. Thanks. Will see what I can do about the log.

Comment: Many thanks...sorted it out. The problem was that the root folder the script was in belonged to root. Changed ownership to another user and the configuration went fine.